# getting distinct values from inputs that share the same name

Tags: django, forms, templates, view, hidden

I have this form in my template:

```
<form method="POST" class="form" action="/groups/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% block hidden_debtors %}
        {% for name, email in debtor_info.items %}
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden-debtor" value="{{email}}">
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
    <input type="text" name="new-debtor" id="round-input" placeholder="Select Debtor(s)"></input>
    <button type="submit" name="add-debtor" class="btn btn-primary">Add Debtor</button>
</form>
```

As you can see the hidden type inputs all share the name "hidden-debtor" however they each have distinct email values. I was wondering how I would be able to access each one of these distinct values in my views.py through a loop or something

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of values in your view like this:

```
request.POST.getlist('hidden-debtor')
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)